# Multiple language support in Universal App

Tags: c#, windows, localization, windows-phone, win-universal-app

This is not a question about standard localization - I know how to localize the app, use resources, `Uid`'s and so on - this works perfectly.

The problem is that the app comes within a *bundle*, therefore when the user installs the app it covers only languages that are selected in device/phone settings. But I would like to provide an option in settings that would allow choosing a language regarding the settings. For this purpose, I can use [ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.globalization.applicationlanguages.primarylanguageoverride.aspx), which works very nice when deployed via VS, but as I've mentioned - version from the store lacks resources, as not all are installed.

Does anybody know how to bypass this bundle behavior?

The problem is also that I'm using MAT (multilingual app toolkit) and my translation comes with *xliff* files. I've spent quite a lot of time to find a way to convert them to *resw* files, without success. Is there any way to do it (or I've to write my own converter)?

Comment: How about setting _Generate app bundle_ to _Never_ in the _Package.appxmanifest_? Or you need to bundle some stuff but not others? I'm not sure if this can be done (but I haven't researched it too much).

Comment: @yasen Once the bundle has been published the next updates must be done with bundle (AFAIK). So it won't work :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ResourceContext:

```
var context = new ResourceContext(); // deliberately not using getForCurrentView()
context.Languages = new string() {"fr-fr"}; 
ResourceMap resourceMap = ResourceManager.Current.MainResourceMap.GetSubtree("Resources");
String str = resourceMap.GetValue("string1", context).ValueAsString;
```

More info at:
['How to load string resources'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965323.aspx#Loading_strings_from_the_Windows_Store_app_manifest) and
['ResourceContext class'ResourceContext class'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.resources.core.resourcecontext.aspx).

PS. I have app in store and there is no problem with changing language without reinstall so all resources must be there

Comment: Sorry for late repley - I was on small holiday. I will give you a sign once I test it. Thanks

Comment: It does not really answer the question. I have the same problem. I have 9 languages in the application. While developing all 9 are available but when the application is installed from the Windows Store it has only the subset of languages which mach the installed into the system ones.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this: [UWP: Resource file for languages is not deployed correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107907/uwp-resource-file-for-languages-is-not-deployed-correctly) you need to get rid of bundle in order for my code from above to work. Or you could check if chosen language is installed in OS and if not you could not allow user to choose it using:

```
Windows.System.UserProfile.GlobalizationPreferences.Languages
```

Comment: As far as I remember, there is a problem with getting rid of bundle, when the app is already published as a bundle - then it can be updated only with a bundle. Has something changed in this manner?

Comment: yeah... unfortunately your right - I ended up telling user to install additional languages in OS