# how to develop Windows phone app in arabic

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I need to develop a windows phone app which is in english and arabic. If selected language is arabic everything should be from right to left  (Like the text in arabic). and in case of english it should be from left to right.

Comment: your question is full of confusion. What exactly you want to achieve what tool you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bi-directional Languages in Windows to achieve that. Here is a link to help you out.
[Bi-directional languages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a9d2b0zt.aspx)

Also look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30772472/multiple-language-support-in-universal-app)